# Visual Basic needs single SQL data call for multiple dropdowns with same data

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a Visual Basic page that has multiple dropdown with the some set of data, but the data is called from a SQL server for its initial creation.  I'm using the same SqlDataSource for all five dropdowns, but I fear it is calling it five times per row per the number of rows I have.  At least, I think it is going slower than it should be.

Here is what I have for each dropdown's code

```
<div dlass="DataDropDownColumn">
    <div>DataDropDownColumnEntry1</div>
    <div class="DropDownSelectionBox">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntry1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Entry1") %>'
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="EntryID" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select" Value="" />
            <aps:ListItem Text=" " Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
<div dlass="DataDropDownColumn">
    <div>DataDropDownColumnEntry2</div>
    <div class="DropDownSelectionBox">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntry2" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Entry2") %>'
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="EntryID" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select" Value="" />
            <aps:ListItem Text=" " Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
<div dlass="DataDropDownColumn">
    <div>DataDropDownColumnEntry3</div>
    <div class="DropDownSelectionBox">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEntry3" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Entry3") %>'
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="EntryID" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Select" Value="" />
            <aps:ListItem Text=" " Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is repeated several times with different IDs for the ddlEntry and different matching DataBinder Evals for the ddlEntry.  Again the DataSourceID for each one is the same:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT ID FROM tblEntries ORDER BY ID"
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My belief is that there are multiple calls for each ddlEntry, even though the data is the same.  Am I mistaken, and ASP is smart enough to just get the data one time, and apply it to all the HTML Dropdown List entries?  It would be nice, but it seems a little slow bringing up the page.

Comment: Test it yourself; swap `SELECT ID FROM tblEntries ORDER BY ID` for `SELECT DATEPART(second, getutcdate()) as ID FROM tblEntries ORDER BY ID` (or NEWID if it's a guid) and step slowly in the debugger.. See if the results in all the dropdowns are the same or different

Comment: @Caius Jard - Thank you for the debugging idea.  It is coming up with separate times for each dropdown.  I had to take it from `second` to `millisecond`, but they all come out different.  Each dropdown's elements in the dropdown had the same result, but checking from one dropdown to the next, it was different.  Any ideas on creating a **control** for the dropdown menu?